# きたんだろう at the end

Tags: translation, meaning

I am bit lost by the きたんだろう in this sentence.

あれはお前が勝手にしてきたんだろう

something like you do what you want with me? 
I read somewhere that this きたんだろう means something like the speaker "knows" what to do. but i am totally confused.

Answer (score 2):

Context is king! I'll try to answer your question, but trying to do it without any context is a pain in the neck.

1. だろう is the form of でしょう, which you use when speaking with a person you're familiar with and you can afford to use it.
2. ん is a contraction of の.

These two forms original, dictionary form would be んだ, alternatively のだ or のです. でしょう (or だろう) when linked with の/ん forms sort of rhetorical question. The speaker seeks agreement, he's not really asking the question.

3. te-form + きた indicates that an action has been taking place over some period of time.
4. 勝手にする means "to do something selfishly".

With these 4 points in mind, I believe the right answer to your question would be something along the lines of "I guess, you've been doing that without any regard to anyone or anything, haven't you?!"

Comment: I am sorry. the only context i have the other girl asks something like "do you want to kiss again" and this is his answer.
So it means if they do kiss this means a lot of trouble. and in that case he just wanna say she doesn't care about the consequences. 

だろう and ん explanation really helped me a lot. thank u. i am sorry next time i ask i'll try to give more context

Comment: While ん is certainly a contraction of の.  だろう is definitely not a contraction of でしょう; rather it's a change in formality/politeness, with だろう being the more familiar term and でしょう being the default level of politeness.  Otherwise, great answer.

Comment: @A.Ellett Yes, my bad. That's the type of shortcut my brain has taken, or takes in general, I should say. I'll edit it.

Comment: Your interpretation of きた is the least likely the case. It's more like "did it and came back" or "did it to me".